# it's always in validating while creating purview account in dogfood environment

Tags: azure, azure-purview

scenarios as below and no any error messages popup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen , I am unable to give you the reason as to why this is happening , but I think you are going to the marketplace and then looking for Purview .
I always go to Azure portal -> All services -> Type in Purview

[image]